# System Verilog function that takes any number of strings as an argument?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl, test-bench

I want to have a SystemVerilog function that can accept any number of string arguments, this function is essentially a wrapper around the in-built `$display` as such I want users to be able to call the function in the same way, passing any number of strings into `myfunc()` as follows:

```
myfunc(stringVar1, "literalString", stringVar2, stringVarN, intVarToConvertToString);
```

My current implementation is to just have a single string arg and use the SystemVerilog concatenation operator to concatenate all the strings I wish to pass; e.g.

```
myfunc({stringVar1, "literalString", stringVar2, stringVarN, intVarToConvertToString});
```

however when I try to pass in a numeric type like `int` as a concatenated string, it isn't being converted into a string representation of its value correctly, and the `�` character is printed in its place. I have also tried to perform an explicit string cast on the non-string types being concatenated but to no avail.

I know that if I got all of the arguments to my function separately I can then just pass them directly to `$display` which does correctly convert the number types to their string representation to display them. Does anyone know how I would do this in System Verilog?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert an integer's value into a string representation, or more specifically, a *"string"* of ASCII digits, you need to use a formatting function, like `$sformatf("%d",intVarToConvertToString)` to convert a value to a decimal representation, or you can combine the concatenation and formatting into a single expression.

```
myfunc($sformat("%s%s%s%d",{stringVar1, "literalString"}, stringVar2, stringVarN, intVarToConvertToString);
```

Answer (score 0):

The *concat* operator `{}` converts its contents in a stream of bits.
There are no variable arguments in verilog/system verilog functions.
There is no way to wrap variable args in a $display.

So your best bet is using dynamic or associative arrays of strings or queues.
The following is an example of a possible use of an associative array:

```
package pkg;
function void multstr(string args[int]);
  for(int i = 0; i < args.num; i++) begin
    $display("arg%0d: %s", i, args[i]);
  end
endfunction
endpackage

module testme();
  string strings[int];
  initial begin
    strings[0] = "hello ";
    strings[1] = "world";
    
    pkg::multstr(strings);
  end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function with a dynamic array port like this:

```
module tb ();
  
  // function arg is a dynamic array of strings
  function void printStrings(string mystrings[]);
    foreach(mystrings[i])
      $display("",mystrings[i]);
  endfunction
                             
  // dynamic array of string
  string names [];
  
  initial
    begin
      names = new[2];
      names = '{"bob","joe"};
      printStrings(names);
      $display("-----");
      // make the d-array 1 bigger
      names = new[names.size() + 1](names);
      names = '{"bob","joe","bill"};
      printStrings(names);
    end
  
endmodule
```

Which produces

```
bob
joe
-----
bob
joe
bill
```

The same thing could be done using a queue as a function port rather than a d-array.